# React native apk generate

Tags: react-native

raushan@raushan:~/bigbuilder/android$ ./gradlew assembleRelease

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Settings file '/home/raushan/bigbuilder/android/settings.gradle' line: 4
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'bigbuilder'.

> Could not read script '/home/raushan/bigbuilder/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[image]

Can some one please suggest what to do now. I am new to react native.

Comment: did you try to do `npm install` or `yarn`, depends on what you are using, in the big builder directory? if not working, please add what do you have in `settings.gradle` to your post

Comment: npm was not working for me.. yarn works and now I cleared this step. The above error is fixed now but there is a new one

////////////////////////////////////////////////
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /home/raushan/bigbuilder/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/background_splash.xml:2: AAPT: error: resource drawable/splash_screen (aka com.big_builder:drawable/splash_screen) not found.

Answer (score 0):

The new error is with linking resources,

one or more of the packages you added to your project **(for example by typing `yarn add react-native-splash-screen`)** is not linked, please when add a new package read the documentation well to see if there is more steps to link it with android or ios.

try `npx react-native link` to link the packages you added to your project, and the run android build by typing `npx react-native run-android`, if did not work try resetting the cache, first stop the running node server the type `npx react-native start --reset-cache`

if the same error still appears you need to see the manual linking steps in the package you added, and I think it is named **"splash_screen"**